# Is there a way to finish the Trello card description editing process without using the mouse?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

Is there a keyboard shortcut for finishing edits to a Trello card's description?

You can use the `[Esc]` key to cancel the edits to a card's description, but once you're in editing mode, the only way I've found to exit editing mode while saving the edits is to click on the Save button with my mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to save your edits without using the mouse.

Comment: Wow.  I could have sworn I tried that!  I must have hit [Ctrl]+[something else]+[Enter] instead!  Thanks for your help!